# Android Room: auto Increment field

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Is there any way to set a field auto increment with android [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)?

There is a table which contains 3 fields: id, name, order. And I want the field `order` to be an auto increment field.

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long id;
private String name;
private int order;
```

Set field as primary key can achieve this, but there is already one `id`.

I can handle the order by myself, maybe set the field `order` as unique is much safer. But I prefer letting the db do it automatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Android doesn't support auto increment. Even for primary key, its not auto-increment, its auto-generate. It won't be serial numbers. It will generate a random hash numbers.

Auto generate is supported only for primary key but not for any normal column

Answer (score -2):

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

Annotate your Entity class with the code above.